# Disabling Wayland / Gnome touch gestures for touch monitor (or entirely)

Tags: sound, touchscreen, wayland, multi-touch, gestures

Has anyone figured out how to disable touch gestures in Gnome when using Wayland? I am used to X11 where I can use full 10-finger multi-touch in Bitwig Studio (a great audio recording tool, for those who don't know), but the newest version of Ubuntu is (and many distros soon are) using the new Wayland compositor, and there are some (admittedly nice) touch gestures which cause any touches > 3 to replace previous touches.

This makes Bitwig's touch-piano and mixer hard to use in any meaningful way.

I would love to keep them for the touchpad but not the monitor.

The disable gestures extension does not currently support 21.10, so I'm not able to lean on that yet.

But, again, I would love to keep using gestures with the touchpad, but just not have them affect touchscreen input.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: A workaround would be to switch to X11 - you still can run Ubuntu desktop on X11 if you wish. Wayland is now default, but not the only possibility - you would then loose touchpad gestures, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, I may have to.  Having just gotten a new laptop, and setting it up with the latest Ubuntu, Wayland has gotten soooo much better.  It'd be a shame to have to switch back over to X11.  I get that gestures are really helpful, but this seems very un-Linux to not be able to enable an incredibly powerful workflow.

It also seems weird in that, almost all these touchscreens are designed to support and understand up to 10 touches, why would these UI helpers curtail the capabilities of the hardware?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the touchscreen completely, I followed this link and it worked like a charm in Ubuntu 21.1 running on an Asus Laptop.

https://www.blackmoreops.com/2016/10/26/disable-touchscreen-linux/

In resume, the article suggest to try the following:

> From the bash, try running the following command
>
> ```bsh
> modprobe -r hid_multitouch
> ```
>
> If it works and you want to make the change permanent do the following:
>
> 1. Create 'hid_multitouch.conf' file under /etc/modprobe.d folder.
> 2. Add the following content to the file:
>
> ```
> # Use following syntax 
> # blacklist driver-name
> blacklist hid_multitouch
> ```
>
> 3. Save the changes and reboot. This time the hid_multitouch module should not be loaded anymore.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198744)

Comment: It makes total sense, thanks for the review David. I will update my answer when I get a chance and will keep your advice in mind for the future

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation to vote down this answer, but I don't want to disable the touchscreen.  Using the touchscreen is the whole point of the question.  I want to disable the gestures.  Or more specifically, I want to be able to not have the gestures disrupt more traditional 10 finger touch capabilities.

How this currently plays out is that if I am adjusting two mixer faders simultaneously, and I press a third finger down on my touchscreen, whatever is tracking touches assumes I'm trying to make a three finger gesture and abruptly disrupts the first two touches.